# Usage of noindex / canonical tag for products in shop

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I have a category in the online shop with around 16000 products. Now the ranking always jumps from the category page to a product page.

My solution was to set the product pages to `noindex`, or would the `canonical` tag be better here?

Note: The content of the category page is different than that of a product page, so the `canonical` tag doesn't actually make sense, right?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to also consider your internal linking structure.

If you want Google to rank a page higher, you can build a silo page or boost a single page with on-page SEO and internal linking etc.

You can also create some UI/UX element above the fold so the user can easily get to the parent category from and product page. A breadcrumb trail can also help as well as short, but descriptive URLs.

The product pages also may have more keywords and some long-tail keywords that bring users to your site that otherwise would not get you any traffic.

I would carefully consider your SEO strategy first before making any big changes.

Answer (score 1):

This not what `canonical` tag is for.

You should use `noindex`. But then Google wont index any of your product pages, it will only index category pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common headache. The reason it is happening is probably a combination:

1. The product page has a lot more backlinks than the category page
2. Your internal link architecture isn't optimized for it - a silo is one strategy that is available, which Dave alluded to, that involves organizing your content into "silos" (or metaphorically "hub and spoke").
3. It has to do with content

Basically, Google thinks that your product page is a more relevant result for the query. Either because external signals (backlinks, social shares, etc) or internal signals (# of internal referring pages, the anchor text on those links, etc). The problem that you need to solve is *why*.

I think the problem is content. Your product page probably has more content about the subject matter than your category page. It's also possible that your category page is unintentionally keyword stuffing. For what it's worth, if it was my site and I was generating income from it, I'd probably make sure I have the bases covered with the content and make sure my UX was good. That's a valid remedy. If the ranking product page is not what users are looking for, if the site is easy enough to navigate, they'll find it.

For what it's worth, Google came out with some new advice recently that basically says you no longer need to go out of your way to optimize content for SEO. Many of my colleagues and friends in the industry have been seeing improvements by "de-optimizing" their pages...*what a time to be alive*.

Once upon a time when Page Rank was a much stronger signal I did the following and it worked out:

- Redirect the ranking product page to the category page. It will inherit it's Page Rank/Link Equity via the 301.
- Create a new page for the ranking product page
- Optimized on-page factors to encourage sitelinks - after a month the client's most popular product page, among others appeared beneath the category result.

While it worked for me, I can't guarantee it will work for you. At the time I  was green and reckless.

The on-page optimization required to get sitelinks is not easy, especially if you're trying to be selective. Ultimately, you are at the whim of Google's algorithm. While I *was* trying to get them, I could have also just got lucky. It requires patience and tinkering. Here's Google's advice around sitelinks:

- Make sure that the text you use as your page titles and in your
  headings is informative, relevant, and compact.
- Create a logical site
  structure that is easy for users to navigate, and make sure you link
  to your important pages from other relevant pages.
- Ensure that your
  internal links' anchor text is concise and relevant to the page
  they're pointing to.
- Avoid repetitions in your content.

[More about sitelinks](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/sitelinks)